# Unable to install Ubuntu 14.04. PC restarts after I click "continue" button in "Install Ubuntu"

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I am unable to install Ubuntu on my hardware because as soon as I enter the installation process and click the "next" button for installing it then it just reboots as if the Flash Drive has stopped working suddenly. This happens to me every time.

I am booting from an USB Flash Drive in UEFI mode because only that is working in my hardware.

My PC already has Linux Mint 16 installed which I want to replace with Ubuntu 14.04 but because of the reasons mentioned here, I am unable to do so.

My hardware is a custom build PC having the following parts :

```
CPU : AMD A8 6600K |
Mobo : MSI-FM2-A55M-E33 |
RAM : Kingston HyperX Blu 4GB RAM |
HDD : Seagate Barracuda 1TB Drive
```

Any help would be highly appreciated as I really want to run 14.04 because of the improved drivers that would help in gaming.

Edit : Posted the same on MSI forums at https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=179619.0 in case if it is a hardware related bug.

Comment: I have this same problem, and my PC also has an AMD A8 6600k along with an MSI motherboard, so I am guessing that a cause to this problem may be the hardware that we have. I am also still trying to figure out a way to fix this, however.

Comment: Same problem here too with AMD A8-5600K...what to do?

Comment: @Dude Hey, what motherboard are you using and is your problem exactly the same as mine?

Comment: I think this is a problem with the 3.13 kernel on the MSI motherboard. I have an a10-5*** and it has shown this problem before when I have tried to upgrade to that kernel on 13.10. Now it is the same with a dvd install of 14.04.

Comment: @comrademike Looks to me like yet another X.org bug. Really excited for Wayland to take over.

Comment: @SangeetKhatri I didn't have this problem with open source drivers on my hp laptop (had other problems with laptop that prevented upgrade :( ). I think it's an msi motherboard setting clashing with the new kernel, perhaps dri or drm stuff

Comment: @comrademike Yes, you are right it looks to me like a kernel bug too because when I am booting a live USB of Mint 16 or other distros with older kernels then there is no such problem.

But when I try to boot Ubuntu 14.04 or Arch which use the 3.13 kernel, only those are causing problems. I think this bug needs to be adressed by Ubuntu developers, but how should I be able to report to them about this?

Comment: @SangeetKhatri It is quite a process https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs ...good luck!

Comment: @comrademike I filed a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1309578

Comment: Great stuff Sangeet! Great start at Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: @comrademike Do you have any idea on how much time does it take for someone to review to bug report?

Comment: In my case, grub2 loads into a non-graphical mode and any selection from the menu just reboots the computer after displaying a black screen for 5 seconds. I have an MSI motherboard with AMD A10-5800K. The only solution was to add a boot parameter of `radeon.dpm=0`.

Answer (score 1):

when boot from USB or DVD you must edit boot options & add this:

`radeon.dpm=0`

Source: aleks-nl5 @ https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=179619.0 24-April-14, 12:38:39