# reboot loop after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: 14.04

After getting the no more support message I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 it seemed to go fine but after about a minute the computer rebooted

then there after it would reboot every 30 sec.-2 minutes. 
Finally wiped hard drive and reinstalled 13.10.

I ordered a 14.04.1 LTS live cd.
It does the same thing, as soon as it gets to the try/install screen it reboots
Tried 64 and 32 bit version, both the same.

Has anyone had this issue or could give me advice?

MSI A88XM-E45 motherboard, A6 processor, 8G memory, 64G SSD sata hd, 1T 7200rpm sata hd

Comment: `> the no more support message` - To put it in perspective, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL - is what it is. I read this as 'there will be less HARDWARE DRIVER UPDATES' - nothing else changes until the `LTS` period is out.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/q/449391/59876 It seems the kernel version 3.13 is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem with my old computer. Since you are upgrading your OS, it can be argued that your system requires overall more power. Make sure that your PSU (power Supply) is able to handle your system. Did you make any recent changes to your hardware?

Comment: computer has a new coolermaster 500w supply

Comment: I would suggest using http://extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp to determin if a 500w PSU is enough for your system. In case you do not know any piece of hardware you are using you can type this 'lspci' in terminal and it will show you.